# Autolayout to Dynamically Resize UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I tried to create dynamic UILabel with every possible way but its not working for me.

I have created UITableViewCell with .xib file as below :

[image]
And Loading above cell on tab table view cell click with dynamic height by using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
It working well but I want UIlabel with yellow colour should update it size dynamically. I have already set all autolayout to label.

I have added :

```
label1.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label1.numberOfLines = 0
```

Also tried with :

```
label1.sizeToFit()
```

It is not updating its height of label 
But when I add newline at end of the assigned string of Lebel it autoresize label height as shown in below image but still its not showing all text.

8 Seater Room, 8 Seater Conference Room, 12 Seater Conference Room(WProjector)

[image]

Is there any other way to Dynamically Resize UILabel ?

Or

Should I use `NSLayoutConstraint` for height to increase height ?

Comment: It seems there is no bottom constraint to superview try to set your lable bottom constraint to superview

Comment: I have added  bottom constraint to superview.

Comment: Remove height constraint.

Comment: @PremaJanoti With height or without height same result.

Comment: can you please show the constraints of "Booking Type" label?

Comment: For `Booking Type` I have set leading, trading, top and width. Bottom constraints not set for booking type

Comment: select label and change content compression resistance Priority to 1000 under Size inspector.

Comment: @tailor its not working. I also tried by specifying cell height manually still not working for all labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to find why my Autolayout to Dynamically Resize UILabel not working.

I almost wasted week to finding and trying different solutions.
It was an issue related to UILabel extension used in the project. 
I had referred some git hub project to show toast message on the screen. In the toast view, they had extended functionality to handle multiline toast message.

This is main disadvantage of using code from open source code.
What I learned from this is we need to understand open source code before adding to the project.

**Note : Please study and understand open source code before adding to your project. Open source code may had some unwanted effects on some of the functionality in your project.**

Thank for all responses.

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour with no third party library. This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: That was it! The extension UILabel was overriding intrinsicContentSize and messing up the height calculation for all labels! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your custom `UITableViewCell` you need setup `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` directly for this specific label. But only when cell already visible and resized to current screen size.

For example:

```
class YourCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
      label1.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label1.frame.size.width
      super.layoutSubviews()
    }

}
```

Comment: `Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'width'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using autolayout, just add top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint to label and set lines for label to 0 from attribute inspector.

check the image below

[image]

this might do the work..!

Comment: You can see in question image 1 I already set all autolayout with respect all labels. Also tried using setting height or without height. Its not working when string assign to label but if I add newline it working.

Comment: i think your tableview cell size does not increase according to label's height, just try giving label height to cell dynamically

Comment: Its already dynamic. I showing this custom UITableViewCell after user click on tableview cell. If it is not dynamic then it will not work when I appended newline character at end of string.

Comment: on run time height of label is 81.5

Comment: and height for that particular tableview cell is?

Answer (score 0):

Output of below solution -

[image]

Try it -

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

label1.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label1.numberOfLines = 0
```

And add constraints properly, for reference please see attached images.

For Dyanmic Label-

[image]

For Booking Type Label-

[image]

For other Labels-
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already tried this it will defiantly work but with cell with .xib file its not working. I want use same cell in multiple views.